# In codechef why my python code is giving NZEC error :-

Tags: python

Input

The first line of the input contains a single integer T

denoting the number of test cases. The description of T
    test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers x and y.

The second line contains three space-separated integers N
    , M and K

The third line contains 2N
    space-separated integers a1,b1,a2,b2,…,aN,bN.

The fourth line contains 2M
    space-separated integers c1,d1,c2,d2,…,cM,dM.

The fifth line contains 2K
    space-separated integers e1,f1,e2,f2,…,eK,fK

Output

For each test case, print a single line containing one real number the minimum distance.

Your answer will be considered correct if its absolute or relative error does not exceed 10^-6.
.

```
import math
T=int(input())
for _ in range(T):
  x,y=map(int,raw_input().split())
  n,m,k=map(int,raw_input().split())
  nr=list(map(int,input().split()))
  mr=list(map(int,input().split()))
  kr=list(map(int,input().split()))
  ar=[x]+[y]
  p,q=[],[]
  for i in range(0,n*2,2):
    for j in range(0,k*2,2):
      p.append(math.sqrt((nr[i]-kr[j])**2+(nr[i+1]-kr[j+1])**2))
  for i in range(0,m*2,2):
    for j in range(0,k*2,2):
      q.append(math.sqrt((mr[i]-kr[j])**2+(mr[i+1]-kr[j+1])**2))
  h=10000000000.00
  for i in range(0,m*2,2):
    d=math.sqrt((ar[0]-mr[i])**2+(ar[1]-mr[i+1])**2)
    for j in range(0,n*2,2):
      d1=math.sqrt((mr[i]-nr[j])**2+(mr[i+1]-nr[j+1])**2)
      c=min(p[j]+d+d1,p[j+1]+d+d1)
      if c < h:
        X=c
  g=10000000000.00
  for i in range(0,n*2,2):
    d=math.sqrt((ar[0]-nr[i])**2+(ar[1]-nr[i+1])**2)
    for j in range(0,m*2,2):
      g=math.sqrt((nr[i]-mr[j])**2+(nr[i+1]-mr[j+1])**2)
      c=min(q[j]+d+d1,q[j+1]+d+d1)
      if c < g:
        g=c
  result=min(h,g)
  print(result)
```

Comment: Please check if using raw_input instead of input works while taking input of mr, nr and kr.